# What is the position hash value and what does it do in XML?

Tags: python, xml

When using XML in something like Python, (e.g. xml Python package) and calling `getchildren()` on a tag, the output is often of the form:

```
[<Element 'date' at 0x2b15236f4e08>]
```

...but what is the name of this bit `0x2b15236f4e08`? Is it the position of the tag in the file? I can't find out anywhere what it means!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`0x2b15236f4e08` is the [identity](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) of a Python object which, in this case, represents a particular XML element named `date`.  It has no meaning at the XML level; it's an implementation detail at the Python level.